# how to pronounce words 'baths' in actual conversation?

Tags: pronunciation, american-accent

I was confused by the pronunciation of consonant cluster 'ths' at the end of the word.

For example: the cluster ***'ths'*** in word months, **according to ESL teaching videos on Youtube**,[video for months' pronunciation on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGM9EqtD0a8) can be pronounced as **/ths/**(which is the pronunciation listed in most of the dictionaries), **/ts/ and /s/**. As for word baths, I could not find a video explanation by searching internet. But I assume that the word ***baths*** should be pronounced as **/baths/ or /bas/**, ***but not*** **/bats/**(As I couldn't think of any rules for this pronunciation)

I'm not sure whether the above descriptions are correct or not, so please correct me if there are any mistakes or exceptions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide a link to these videos, or at least one that makes this claim.

Comment: In NAmE, it's **bæθs**. In BrE, it's **bɑːðz** .

Comment: \ˈbathz, ˈbaths, ˈbäthz, ˈbäths\ (Merriam-Webster)

Comment: @Max I already add a link for months

Comment: @P.E.Dant  /bæθs/ is a very proper pronunciation for this word, but are there any people pronounce it as /bæts/ in real speech?

Comment: Interesting. Everyone should understand you if you use the "th" in months, but I never really noticed what the lady said in the video. I guess people do say "muhns". Here's a children's song I found on [months](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPeAo1hz8GA). He says "muhns". This might be similar for "baths".

Comment: In nearly 70 years as a North American native English speaker, and having travelled throughout the world,  I have never heard _baths_ pronounced without the _th_ sound, but @HenryWang should bear in mind that anyone (in the free world) can create and publish a video that demonstrates any pronunciation they choose. I could create and publish a video demonstrating that the word is pronounced _Bartz,_ and would be no one to stop me.

Comment: @P.E.Dant (and everyone), I don't think her idea that we pronounce *months* with a schwa (i.e., /mənθs/ or /məns/, which is transcribed as "muhnths" and "muhns" in the video) is very realistic. (I can't decide whether her "s" in "muhns" is an /s/ or a /z/, but I think it's more like an /s/.) If it were really a schwa, *month* won't rhyme with *once* like in the children's song Max mentioned.

Comment: You may want to look at youglish site. They provide 225 results for the words baths:
http://youglish.com/search/baths

Comment: @P.E.Dant I think there are only two ways to pronounce the word baths

Comment: No doubt the pronunciation varies from place to place. Rather than trying to figure out which is "correct", I would focus on the expected environment where you will be using English. If non native English, it probably doesn't matter because as long as it is close it will be understood in context. If native English, just pronounce it the way they do.

Comment: I am going to reopen this question.  Dictionaries generally present what is called a **careful pronunciation**, not necessarily taking into account fast speech rules, consonant cluster reduction, assimilation, and so on.  It is clear to me from the title that the OP wants to know about the *actual* pronunciation, not the *careful* pronunciation we use in theory.  They might be the same in this particular case, but that information belongs in an answer, not in a close reason.

Comment: @snailplane +1 Very well reasoned and a worthwhile caution generally  to those who, like me, are sometimes too hasty in closing. "_That information belongs in an answer, not in a close reason"_ is, as we might have said in USENET, ".sig material."

Answer (score 2):

You're right that "baths" would not be expected to ever be pronounced with a [t] sound.

It's only possible to have [t] in "months" because of the "n" preceding the "th." When a nasal consonant such as /m/, /n/ or /ŋ/ (the "ng" sound in "sing") precedes a voiceless fricative consonant such as /f/, /s/ or /θ/ (the "th" sound in "thin"), many speakers introduce an epenthetic voiceless plosive. The identity of this plosive depends on which nasal consonant is present: we get [p] after /m/, [t] after /n/, and [k] after /ŋ/.

This means that "month" (most commonly transcribed /mʌnθ/) may be pronounced as [mʌntθ]. Both variants, [mʌnθ] and [mʌntθ], are generally considered to be standard English.

I've never noticed the plural being pronounced as [mʌnts] or [mʌns], but that wouldn't surprise me too much as [mʌntθs] has a rather awkward four-consonant cluster that seems like it would be prone to simplification in a similar way to /siksθs/. This pronunciation is mentioned in another, related question: [Do most Americans pronounce 'months' as 'mons', and 'clothes' as 'clos'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/91125/do-most-americans-pronounce-months-as-mons-and-clothes-as-clos)

In the word "bath," there is no nasal consonant preceding the /θ/ sound, so you cannot insert an epenthetic [t]. (Speakers of some varieties of English might outright replace the /θ/ in this word with a [t] sound, a phenomenon called "[th-stopping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-stopping)", but this is not standard and would not be taught to ESL learners.)

The plural "baths" may be subject to another process however: fricative voicing. In English, words that end in a voiceless fricative sometimes have voiced fricatives in their plural forms. The voiceless fricatives /f/, /s/, /θ/ correspond to the voiced fricatives /v/, /z/, /ð/ respectively.

In cases where the voiceless fricative is voiced, the plural suffix "-s" is also pronounced as a voiced consonant /z/.

For the word "baths," voicing the fricative is optional. So you may hear it pronounced with either /ðz/ or /θs/.

I don't have enough knowledge of phonetics to say if these clusters are ever reduced in fast speech to single consonants [z] or [s]. But I would say your target pronunciation for the word "baths" should end in a cluster of two consonants.

Answer (score 0):

Not all words that end in *ths* reduce this cluster in the way that it is often done  for *months*. *Baths* is not reduced in this way.

\ˈbathz, ˈbaths, ˈbäthz, ˈbäths\ (Merriam-Webster)

For further information about the reduced  pronunciation of *months*, see [How to distinguish 'month' and 'months' in pronunciation?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58985/how-to-distinguish-month-and-months-in-pronunciation)